# django read mp3 file and send it as response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**views.py**

```
from . import models, serializers
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class getSongData(APIView):
    serializer_class=serializers.SongSerializer

    def get(self, request, id, format=None):
        serializer = serializers.SongSerializer(models.Song.objects.get(id=id))
        file_loc = serializer.data['audio_file'] # go below to see the data

        # read the mp3 file

        return Response(file_data)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('songs/audio/<int:id>', views.getSongData.as_view(), name='audio')
]
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models

class SongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Song
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    audio_file = models.FileField()
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
```

**The data**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Kubbi | Cascade",
        "audio_file": "/media/Kubbi__Cascade.mp3",
        "genre": "Instrumental",
        "created_at": "2021-07-24T10:21:48Z"
    }
]
```

When the user clicks on a song (lets say the song's id=1), a request gets sent to 'http://localhost:8000/api/songs/audio/1' then in views.py I extract the song's location via serializer.data['audio_file'] which is = "/media/Kubbi__Cascade.mp3", all i want to do is to read this audio file and send the data as a Response back to the frontend, I tried many solutions but they were throwing errors...

Comment: are you meaning to return playable audio as a file?

Comment: yes, so that the user can play/download it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do it using pure django this would work

```
from django.http import FileResponse


class getSongData(APIView):
    serializer_class=serializers.SongSerializer

    def get(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
        song = models.Song.objects.get(id=id)        
        return FileResponse(song.audio_file.open())
```

but preferably you should serve files through a reverse proxy for better performance.